# css vertical background color or image centering

Tags: css

I have a problem. I want to center the second `div`

```
<div class="a">
<div class="b">

</div>
</div>


<style>
.a {
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
   background: #000000;
}
.b {
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   background: #454545;
   float: right;
}
</style>
```

I want to center the letter b like `line-height: 300px;`

Comment: Want something like this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/uwfosLgp/2) ?

Comment: nope. i need the margin to be in right. sorry i didnt put it in code. post edited now =)

Comment: Updated the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/uwfosLgp/4). please check

Comment: thank you very much. problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, what you want is, to vertically-align the *inner* `<div>` as compare to its *parent* `<div>`.

So for that you've to slightly change your code as:

**CSS**:

```
.a {
      width: 400px;
      height: 300px;
      background: #000000;
      vertical-align: middle;
      display: table-cell;
}
```

And by this you're good to go.